# Drupal Rule to Clear a Field But Still Retain Data?

Tags: views, rules

Need advice on fufilling this use case:

Use Case:

When User edits the node the first time, he populates *Field A*, a text area.  The data from *Field A* is eventually displayed on *View A*.

When User or other User returns to edit the same node, *Field A* is cleared for convenience, ready for new text input. (But the original data is still in the DB, and displayed in *View A*).

When the User saves the page this second time, the new data replaces the previous data in *View A*.

Plus: Eventually,  I also need to display the history of *Field A* in the application from all the saved edits.

Answer (score 1):

Use [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) with FORM_ID = node_form.

Example:

```
function your_module_name_form_node_form_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
  $form['field_a']['#default_value'] = '';
}
```

For the second portion of your question, look into [Node revisions](https://www.drupal.org/node/320614).

Comment: Can you provide some guidance on how to implement this code?

Comment: Are you familiar with writing modules for Drupal?  I assumed that was your plan.  You would either need to find a module that already does what you want, or write your own and include this code.  If you have no experience with writing modules, you can take a look at [this guide](https://www.drupal.org/node/1074360).